# C# "cannot implicitly convert type" same model properties

Tags: c#, .net, linq, model-view-controller

I'm trying to use a ViewModel in C# MVC .NET Visual Studio. I have this mode that's filled with data. It's built up like so:

```
public class Offer
{
    public List<ProjectleaderModel> Projectleaders { get; set; } = new List<ProjectleaderModel>();
    public List<OfferManagerModel> OfferManagers { get; set; } = new List<OfferManagerModel>();
    public List<ProductModel> Products { get; set; } = new List<ProductModel>();
    public List<PersonModel> People { get; set; } = new List<PersonModel>();
    public string Administration { get; set; }
    public string Status { get; set; }
    public DateTime Applicationdate { get; set; }
    public DateTime Submitdate { get; set; }
    public Boolean CustomerAgreementBoolean { get; set; }
    public DateTime CustomerAgreementBooleanDate { get; set; }



}

public class ProjectleaderModel
{
    public int Id;
    public string Name;

}
```

And in my viewmodel I'm trying to get data into a separate list I want to turn into a dropdown-menu:

```
    public List<Offer> Offermodel = new List<Offer>();
    public List<ProjectleaderModel> Projectleaders
    {
        get
        {
            return Offermodel.Select(x => x.Projectleaders).ToList();
        }
    }
```

The Projectleadermodel class is in the model, as you can see. 
Why is it that I'm getting the error:

`Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<System.Collections.Generic.List<EnqueryApp.Model.ProjectleaderModel>>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<EnqueryApp.Model.ProjectleaderModel>'`

Comment: I'm apologize for my edit. I'm accidentally broke question formatting. Now I've reverted it to original revision

Comment: No problem! Thanks for helping, though!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The line `Offermodel.Select(x => x.Projectleaders)` will give you a collection of `Offer` class objects, which then you're making a list of.

But the return type of your `Projectleaders` property is `List<ProjectleaderModel>`

So they aren't a match.

You need to create a list of `Projectleaders` objects to return from that property.

Essentially:

```
return Offermodel.SelectMany(x => x.Projectleaders).ToList();
```

Comment: Can't believe I bumped my head into this for so long while the answer was 4 letters away. Thanks! You weren't first to answer, but I like that you gave a proper explanation.

Answer (score 3):

If you want all project leaders from all offers, then use `SelectMany`

```
return Offermodel.SelectMany(x => x.Projectleaders).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

Notice that `Offer.Projectleaders` is of type `List<ProjectleaderModel>`, hence your `Select` will yield `IEnumerable<List<ProjectleaderModel>>` instead of desired `IEnumerable<ProjectleaderModel>`. Linq has a way around that in form of [SelectMany extension method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/bb534336(v=vs.110).aspx).

Given that your `Projectleaders` can read

```
public List<ProjectleaderModel> Projectleaders =>
        Offermodel.SelectMany(x => x.Projectleaders).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   public List<Offer> Offermodel = new List<Offer>();
    public List<List<ProjectleaderModel>> Projectleaders
    {
        get
        {
            return Offermodel.Select(x => x.Projectleaders).ToList();
        }
    }
```

What you're doing is trying to get a List of the Project Leaders, but Project Leaders is already a list object, so you're getting a list of a list.